# How to change audio file bitrate (bits per second) in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I need to write App in swift that records audio from mice and listen it, then lets user pick bitrate(bits per second) like(320 kbps, 256 kbps, 120 kbps) and listen again. The propose is that get recognizable audio in lower bitrate( if bitrate low, then the file is also small). Can you guys show me, or tell me where and how i can change bitrate of audio file in swift?

I was able only to record sound, now i need a way to let user pick bitrate, then change file to that bitrate, and let user listen to it, maybe save on disk ( file should be smaller than original, because less bits per second). If you know what to do, please help :)

```
func startRecording() {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.6, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
        
        recordButton.setTitle("Tap to Stop", for: .normal)
        
        let audioURL = RecordWhistleViewController.getWhistleURL()
        print(audioURL.absoluteString)
        
        let settings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
            AVSampleRateKey: 12000,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
        ]
        
        do {
            whistleRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: settings)
            whistleRecorder.delegate = self
            whistleRecorder.record()
        } catch {
            finishRecording(success: false)
        }
    }
```

and save file on disk

```
class func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        return documentsDirectory
    }

    class func getWhistleURL() -> URL {
        return getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("whistle.m4a")
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code, what you tried.

Comment: Using different bitrates when recording audio and resampling an existing recording at a different bitrate are 2 very different things, and will yield different results (resampling a recording is destructive, and the results will usually be inferior to sampling the audio at the target bitrate in the first place.) If you goal is to let users determine the lowest usable bitrate, then downsampling a high-bitrate recording will only give your users a rough idea of what it will sound like to record at that bitrate.

Comment: My goal is to resample an existing recording at a different bitrate. Let user pick bitrate then let him listen to it and maybe save on device.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should provide some code for use, show what you tried and where to stuck. I'm just guessing about the technology what you use:

If you use AVAudioRecorder, you can  setup the bitrate when create the recorder:

```
var recorder: AVAudioRecorder?
var bitRate = audioBitrate
var sampleRate = 44100.0
var channels = 1

let settings: [String: AnyObject] = [
            AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(value: Int32(kAudioFormatAppleLossless) as Int32),
            AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue as AnyObject,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: bitRate as AnyObject,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: channels as AnyObject,
            AVSampleRateKey: sampleRate as AnyObject
        ]
        
recorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: url, settings: settings)
recorder?.prepareToRecord()
```

Comment: My goal is to resample an existing recording at a different bitrate. Let user pick bitrate then let him listen to it and maybe save on device. Currently I am recording mice Audio using AVAudioSession, and AVAudioRecorder